# Search in AD from VSTO

Tags: c#, active-directory, vsto

I use FW 4.5 and develop Add-in for WORD 2016. 
In add-in I need search in AD, I use the next code :

```
string ldapPath = "LDAP://OU=Ingegneria,DC=xxx,DC=xxx";
DirectoryEntry searchRoot = GetEntry(ldapPath, adminUser, adminPassword);


DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot)
{
    SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
    Filter = "(&" +
    "(objectClass=user)" +
    "(givenname=s*)" +
    "(samaccountname=*100)" +
")"
};

search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname");
SearchResultCollection result = search.FindOne();
```

Every query take about 800 miliseconds.

BUT At the same computer , same code outside of add-in(tester)  : 
first search take about 800 miliseconds , and after this every search take about 25 miliseonds.

What the problem  with add-in?  And what can I do ?

Comment: what happened? did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you cache the `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher`?

Try this:

```
DirectoryEntry searchRoot;
DirectorySearcher search;

public SearchResultCollection SearchAd(string prop){
    // Define other methods and classes here
    string ldapPath = "LDAP://OU=Ingegneria,DC=xxx,DC=xxx";
    searchRoot = searchRoot ?? GetEntry(ldapPath, adminUser, adminPassword);


    search = search ?? new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot)
    {
        SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
        Filter = "(&" +
        "(objectClass=user)" +
        "(givenname=s*)" +
        "(samaccountname=*100)" +
    ")"
    };

    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(prop);
    return search.FindOne();
}
```